# How to check if correct drivers have been installed for my GPU?

Tags: gpu, gpu-driver

On my Ubuntu, how do i check if correct drivers, supplied by manufacturers have been installed on my Ubuntu instead of generic drivers ?

Comment: I usually use `sudo lshw -C display` with the kernel module (*driver*) rather easily recognized with the `driver=` before it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use `sudo lshw -C display` with the kernel module (*driver*) rather easily recognized with the `driver=` before it..

```
guiverc@d7050-next:~/uwn/issues/777$   sudo lshw -C display
[sudo] password for guiverc: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 530
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       resources: irq:125 memory:ee000000-eeffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```